# Cakephp 3 i18n not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have cake 3 fresh installation.

I have a simple `po` file in this location `src/Locale/de_DE/default.po` with the following content.

```
msgid "test"
msgstr "test in german"
```

On my home page template file I have simple `<?php echo __('test'); ?>`

I need to set the locale on the fly, so I add this to my `AppController's beforeFilter(or initialize)` - `I18n::locale('de_DE');` however `test` is not being translated. I can't figure out, what Im missing. I tried renaming all to iso2 - `de`, but it did not translate either.

Thanks

Comment: Have you cleared the cache (`tmp/cache/persistent`)?

Comment: @ndm, though debug is on, but I cleared the cache as well, same thing

Answer (score 5):

Open your Terminal, cd to your project folder (the one which contains the bin folder) and type:

```
bin/cake cache clear_all
```

That's all. Refresh your page right after.
One last thing, be sure to place your .po files in:

```
Locale/de_DE/your_translations.po
```

I like to use [POEdit](https://poedit.net/) to manage my translations. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

If you are working on a local maschine and use `bin/cake i18n`to generate the translation files, make sure the **files are readable** by your local webspace.

This drove me cracy.